# DataGridView does not show all rows at first (.NET 3.5/VB 2008)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I fill the DGV by looping through a dataset and adding a DGV row for each datarow. After this the DGV.RowCount = DataSet.Rows.Count. Funny thing is that the DGV shows only a part of it (19 of 2448 in my example). After some testing I figured out that the rows show up if I change the Window size a bit.

So now I use a work-around by including the following code after I've filled the DGV:

```
frmMain.Height = frmMain.Height + 1
frmHoofd.Height = frmHoofd.Height - 1
```

This works, but I'm wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in regards to the databinding.  I feel restricted when utilizing Microsofts's databindings.  I like to utilize unbound datasource's which expands my ability to manipulate the data.  On to your question which sounds like you possibly have a docking issue.  Is the datagridview displaying space  below the displayed rows as in a blank space where rows should be? I would check your dock settings to ensure you have the datagridview docked.

The only setting I know of that limits the datagridview's ability to display rows is the DoubleBuffered property which can only be accessed via inheriting a datagridview as mentioned in an answer to my own question regarding a datagridview's DoubleBuffering property.

[How do I override Microsoft's datagridview to allow back buffering in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637175/how-do-i-override-microsofts-datagridview-to-allow-back-buffering-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be because of some default settings of DGV. From the description you given it looks like you are not using databinding. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I'm not using databinding and prefer to not use it. I examined the properties of the DGV but cannot find anything that explains this behaviour.